# Find all link counts in link_stat for a whole domain

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to find all the stats for a whole domain in the link_stat table?

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "http://www.facebook.com"
```

LIKE "http://facebook.com%" wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an easy way. The only way I've found to do it is to manually add all the urls to an `IN` comparison.

```
WHERE url IN ('url1', 'url2', ..., 'urln')
```

Trying to use `CONTAINS()` here gives an error `The link_stat table does not support search.`

Comment: What is it actually searcing for? When I posted URL that im searching for in my facebook status update, it didnt increase share count. But when I pasted URL from another page inside domain it did increment the share count.

Comment: I'm really not sure. I've got some pages that have shares that when I tried this query didn't return anything. Other pages that people don't typically share return higher numbers. The syntax matters in these urls as well: `example.com/mypage` != `example.com/mypage/`